# Html, css 2 images in 1 div, align not work

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have a problem in HTML, CSS.
I have 1 div and 2 images in him.
The first image it's background, the second image it's an avatar image which I can not bring to the center.
I tryed with margin:0 auto; and display:block; but not work.

Html page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzi9s.jpg

How should it look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgX6C.jpg

```
.avatar {
width: 15%;
position:absolute; 
}

.img-home {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.content {
float:right;
width:75%;
height: 100rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="images/avatar.png" class="avatar">

  <img src="images/bg.jpeg" class="img-home">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, post your code rather than image as it really doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background image for the container div directly with css using the property :

```
background-image: url("paper.gif");
```

For the avatar alignment, i'd personally use flex-box. Here's a complete example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
     .container {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         height: 800px;
         width: 1200px;
         background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/36744/agriculture-arable-clouds-countryside.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-size: cover;
     }

     .image{
         width: 300px;
         height: 400px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://www.mercurynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/craig_03.jpg?w=620" class="image"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: np. please be aware that flex container might not work with older browser. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex